# Template function in constructor

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, default-value

I'm implementing a binary search tree from "Data Structures & Algorithms in C++". But I don't quite understand their constructor:

```
Entry(const K& k = K(), const V& v = V())
    : _key(k), _value(v) { }
```

Are `_key` and `_value` functions? Since they default to functions in the constructor?

This is the class header:

```
template <typename K, typename V>
class Entry
{
public:
    typedef K Key;
    typedef V Value;
public:
    Entry(const K& k = K(), const V& v = V()) : _key(k), _value(v) { }
    const K& key() const { return key; }
    const V& value() const { return value; }
    void set_key(const K& k) { _key = k; }
    void set_value(const V& v) { _value = v; }
private:
    K _key;
    V _value;
};
```

Apologies if duplicate, I didn't know what to search for.

Edit: my question is not about the double colon, but the default value `_key` and `_value` are set to: `K& k = K()` and `V& v = V()`. Do these imply that the typenames `K` and `V` are functions?

Comment: try this for fun: `int myint = int()`

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot Ah, I get it. Thank you!